# Active Directory query get ou from user(parent of user)

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I know `cn` and `sAMAccountname`, how to get `OrganizationalUnit` with them.

```
(&(ObjectClass=OrganizationalUnit)(sAMAccountname=name))
```

It's doesn't work.

What's `SELECT`'s sql query in ldap query

```
SELECT OrganizationalUnit FROM table WHERE sAMAccountname=name
```

I'm a newbie for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Objectclass is misspelled.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work either.

Comment: User accounts don't have an `OrganizationalUnit` attribute - they could as well be stored in another type of container. To get the parent container, split the `distinguishedName` value of the user account by the first comma. What language are you working with?

Comment: Get `distinguishedName` form query and split in coding?

Comment: Yes. If you want hints/examples of how to do so, let us know what language your trying to do this in

Comment: C#.First, I try to do it myself. :)